# Setting Substr to larger than string length

Tags: php

This is more of underlying PHP execution question.

What are the **positives or negatives** to the two following methods for limiting string size?

```
function max_length($string, $length) {
  return (strlen($string) > $length)?substr($string, 0, $length):$string;
}

substr($string, 0, $length);
```

The case I am worried about is when the **string is smaller than the length requested.**  Can it cause buffer overflow errors?  Extra whitespace?  Repeated characters?

The only thing I do know is that speed-wise, `substr` is at least **2x faster** than the custom function provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see in https://www.php.net/substr

```
If length  is given and is positive, the string returned will contain
**at most** length  characters beginning from start  (depending on the
length of string ).
```

That means you won't get any extra characters, just the ones you're asking for.

Answer (score 2):

No, nothing to worry about. If the specified length argument is higher than the length of the string - **the whole string, and nothing else** - will be returned. So just go with:

```
$maxString = substr($string, 0, $length);
```